# Is it possible to identify which AWS LoadBalancer is the source?

Tags: amazon-elb

I have set up an AWS structure with 3 Load Balancers that points to 3 Target Groups. These 3 targets groups have instances from the **same** AutoScaling group (I need three redundant Load balancers that my users access to it).

Instances in the autoscaling group have an HaProxy server running (with "frontend accept-proxy and backend send-proxy), that dispatch the requests to 4 instances of my code running via Supervisor.

On my servers, when a user connects, I need to know which Load Balancer they connected to (LB-A, LB-B or LB-C) in order to return an appropriate response.

Is there a way to know from my code which LoadBalancer was used?

Comment: Elastic Load Balancing publishes a log file for each load balancer node every 5 minutes. The load balancer can deliver multiple logs for the same period.
Each log contains the client's IP address and request paths. This may help you to get the idea which node is receiving which IP address. 

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-access-logs.html#access-log-file-format

Comment: Is it possible to know in realtime? Like getting the source IP that connects to my EC2 instance, which would be the IP of the LoadBalancer, doing a reverse would yield it's name and allowing me to identify it. I use Proxy v2 in the target group, to know the real user ip.

Comment: The logfile in S3 publishes at S3 every 5 minutes. You can check all the logs there. I don't believe there is any dashboard that offers a real-time IP address view in the AWS. However, you can check if cloudwatch detailed monitoring can work for you. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-cloudwatch-metrics.html